# jQuery toggle slide animation

Tags: jquery, toggle, slide

I've created custom toggle slide animation. Its working fine as expected but its not sliding on first click. if you click on map arrow then you will see the toggle class will apply to it but map will not slide. but if you click twice more then it will slide.

I'm quite new to jquery and I've also searched alot on it but nothing find any solution. Here is the code;

```
$('.map_btn').click(function() {
    $('.map_btn').toggleClass('toggle');

    $('.map_btn').on('click', function() {
        $('.map_wrapper').stop().animate({
            opacity: 1,
            height: 420
        });
    });
    $('.map_btn.toggle').on('click', function() {
        $('.map_wrapper').stop().animate({
            opacity: 0,
            height: 0
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2fh6/

Comment: Why are you setting the `$.on()` methods after the click? That's a setter only at that first fire. That's your problem. Move them out of the first `$.click()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current solution is that the classes are getting messed up somewhere in the `toggleClass()` and also the fact that you've nested a `click` handler for `.map_btn` within another `click` handler for the same element.

The flow gets a bit messed up, hence.

You can try this,

```
$('.map_btn').toggle(function() {
    $('.map_btn').toggleClass('toggle');
    $('.map_wrapper').stop().animate({
        opacity: 1,
        height: 420
    });
}, function() {
    $('.map_btn').toggleClass('toggle');
    $('.map_wrapper').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0,
        height: 0
    });
});​
```

Use only the `.toggle()` so you don't have to write 2 separate methods.

Fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/h2fh6/20/

You can read more about toggle [here](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: That's great. Good to hear :-) Please accept any answer which has helped answer your question. Will encourage people to help you in future. It's how SO works :-)

Answer (score 3):

Unless you needed the class for something else just use [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/).

```
$('.map_btn').toggle(function() {
    $('.map_wrapper').stop().animate({
        opacity: 1,
        height: 420
    });
},function() {
    $('.map_wrapper').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0,
        height: 0
    });
});
```

I really think they should have named this function **toggleClick**.

Comment: @user1398384 : I think this wont change the icon animations(blue arrow -> grey arrow  on toggle) . see my answer with these working.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of the requery in the handlers.

Comment: @user1398384 - This is not toggling the `.toggle` class on the button, at least not on my Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/h2fh6/23/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$('.map_btn').toggle(function() {
 $('.map_btn').toggleClass('toggle');
$('.map_wrapper').stop().animate({
    opacity: 1,
    height: 420
});
},function() {
 $('.map_btn').toggleClass('toggle');
$('.map_wrapper').stop().animate({
    opacity: 0,
    height: 0
});
});​
```

Comment: Every time that fires, you're dispatching two new queries on top of the one you have to set the handlers up. Save, reuse, private scope above the scope of use (see my answer and how I cache win the `$.load()` closure for an example).

Answer (score 0):

The below code should work with your icon animations!

http://jsfiddle.net/epinapala/h2fh6/19/

```
$('.map_btn').toggle(function() {
    $('.map_btn').toggleClass('toggle');
    $('.map_wrapper').stop().animate({
        opacity: 1,
        height: 420
    });
},function() {
    $('.map_btn').toggleClass('toggle');
    $('.map_wrapper').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0,
        height: 0
    });
});
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it, with caching of the selectors that get recalled (and the obvious closure scope, which is why I put the `$(window).load();` in there), you will have better overall performance.

You have to cache if you're animating. You have to. Do not animate over and over on a reselecting jQuery object call like `$('.map_wrapper').stop().animate()`. It's inefficient, and should only be done when necessary, as when the DOM has been modified and needs to find current state.

My approach just toggles the `effect` variable with new settings if the `.toggle` is found on the button. Simple, reliable. There does seem to be a slight lag at times as the `iframe` loads from Google Maps. That may be unavoidable in the jsFiddle environment.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var $mapbtn = $('.map_btn'),
        $wrapper = $('.map_wrapper');

    $mapbtn.click(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            effect = { opacity: 0, height: 0 };

        $this.toggleClass('toggle');

        if ($this.is('.toggle')) {
            effect.opacity = 1;
            effect.height = 420;
        }

        $wrapper.stop().animate(effect);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/h2fh6/21/